# Low power consumption application

Tags: hardware

In a non mobile application which is powered by a battery and it has to be powered on during weeks without recharging it.

Is Android suitable? Or an embedded Linux is better ?

Android has a power management feature, but can we control it or is it something "automatic" ?

Comment: Does the app require any sort of network access or interaction? Phones with large (>=4000mAh) batteries and tablets can easily make >2 weeks of standby in airplane mode (tablets can even make >4), but once WiFi or cellular is on, or a wakelock is in the background, nothing stays live for more than a week.

Comment: I have to be in a sleep mode (not airplane because it's not a phone) and when I have data comming from internet wake up the system. But maybe is a wakelock that do the job?

Comment: Sounds like a push mechanism should do. I don't have further knowledge in that, unfortunately.

Comment: Android would be  overkill.

Comment: Is there no systems like APM or ACPI in Linux for Android? Can't we control the power consumption of the chip at a very low level?